# Scrape text from a node except last child's text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape quotes from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes). I just need the quote, not the author name.

Below is the HTML source.

```
<div class="quoteText">
      “Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”
  <br>  ―
    <a class="authorOrTitle" href="/author/show/61105.Dr_Seuss">Dr. Seuss</a>
</div>
```

I tried below but it comes with author info.

```
quotes = [quote.text.strip() for quote in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'quoteText'})]
```

I also tried using `contents[0]` but that fails in case of multiline quotes. See below:

```
<div class="quoteText">
      “You've gotta dance like there's nobody watching,
<br>
Love like you'll never be hurt,
<br>
Sing like there's nobody listening,
<br>
And live like it's heaven on earth.”
  <br>  ―
    <a class="authorOrTitle" href="/author/show/1744830.William_W_Purkey">William W. Purkey</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the simple one when you do `quote.text.strip()` you get `'“Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”\n    ―\n    Dr. Seuss'` in that case you can just split out string with `\n` and get the quote only.
Ex.:
`[quote.text.strip().split("\n")[0] for quote in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"quoteText"})]`

if you don't want quotes(i.e. ” and “) you can replace it by `""` using `.replace()`